# Remoteapps on Server 2016 running app inside virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

Hey all I have a program that just wont run on **Server 2016** (it's a quite old program) and so I setup a VM using **Virtualbox** inside the **Server 2016** and installed **Windows XP SP3** (this is only for my home so no need to warn me about that :) ) onto it and installed that program on that - which works just fine running now inside the **Virtualbox** but I need to be able to run it in my **remoteapps** on **Server 2016**.

My question is - Since I have **remoteapps** already setup on **Server 2016** how can I use that in order to run the app in **Virtualbox** from the **Server 2016** **remoteapps**?

Would something along the lines of **App-V** be more appropriate for my current setup more than using **Virtualbox**? If so, how would I configure that?

Comment: "Would something along the lines of App-V be more appropriate for my current setup more than using Virtualbox?" - No;  Was this application by chance a 16-bit program?

Comment: I am making the assumption the application is a legacy third-party application, and for that reason, it wouldn't be realistic or possible to perform the required actions to package it nto an App-V application.